# Save/Load canvas from a paint-game

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have coded a VERY simple "paint-game" that only have the collor black right now. The code is

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("drawingPad");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var isMouseDown = false;
var mouseX = 0;
var mouseY = 0;

context.strokeStyle = "#000000"; // Målar våra svarta strokes som blir vår pensel

// När användaren aktiverar muspekaren på vår canvas
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown",function (evt) {
isMouseDown = true;

mouseX = evt.offsetX;
mouseY = evt.offsetY;

context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(mouseX, mouseY);
});


window.addEventListener("mouseup",function (evt) {
isMouseDown = false;
});

// När användaren flyttar på muspekaren
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove",function (evt) {
if (isMouseDown) {
mouseX = evt.offsetX;
mouseY = evt.offsetY;

context.lineTo(mouseX, mouseY);
context.stroke();
}
});
```

The next step im looking for is some way to save a canvas and then later on load other pictures that you draw before. I have been looking for a answer, maybe local storage is the way to go, or is it a easier way to do it? 
(i'm very new to canvas and i only have smal knowledge in JS and HTML/CSS)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using pixels only, you could use `imageData`:

```
var data = canvas.getImageData(0,0, width, height);
```

Now you only need to send an AJAX request (to prevent page load) to your server and send the imagedata to a database. Something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/api/storeData',
    data: data,
    dataType: 'application/json'
});
```

After you could make a button that retrieves imagedata from the sever with a GET request.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: '/api/getData',
    success: onSuccess
});
```

And using method `putImageData()` to renew your image:

```
canvas.putImageData(data, 0, 0);
```

And then you have your imagedata back!

Comment: Hey! thanks for the help. I have never used json and almost no ajax at all. If you have the time to put it all together and put it on jsfiddle it would be great, otherwise thanks for the help!

Comment: Here's an example 'game' i made using imageData: http://jsfiddle.net/kychan/862U9/4/  I wrote it chock full with comments, so you can understand what i'm doing at every line! For AJAX, you should search online for documentations, tutorials, best practices, etc. If i write a script for you, you won't learn anything :). I recommend using JQuery (browser compatibility and nifty functions). Good luck!

Comment: I checked your game and i cant really understand enough to use it so i can make a save/load function on my game. My understanding in canvas is really bad, but thanks for trying to help me!

Comment: Omg, i wrote the whole game specially for you! What part do you not understand? `canvas.getImageData(0, 0, width, height)` returns a clamped `Uint8ClampedArray` which is a one-dimensional array with `R`,`G`, `B, `A` values of every pixel. Everything on the canvas uses is this one-dimensional array for drawing. Say, you have an canvas with width: 400 and height: 400. The array will contain 400*400*4 indexes. You can store this data on the server, in-memory or locally. You can also use the `.toDataUrl()` to retrieve the image itself.

Comment: Im sorry if you feel like it was a waste of time, i really do! But im so bad at canvas, just started to try this out and alot of your code is new to mee. I want my game but with your save/load function, and i dont know what parts i should use from your code and if i have to change any of it to make it fit.